# How to add an editor for one element of location or rotation_euler

Tags: python

I what to add a Panel to edit some property of some objects. Here is my code:

```
import bpy

class LayoutPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Panel with funny layout"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "TOOL_PROPS"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        cube = bpy.context.scene.objects["Cube"]
        layout.prop(cube, "location")
        layout.prop(cube, "rotation_euler")

bpy.utils.register_class(LayoutPanel)
```

Here is the panel GUI:

[image]

However I want to only add a slider editor for only the x-axis location and rotation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[`UILayout.prop(...)`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.UILayout.html#bpy.types.UILayout.prop)**

> - **index** (int in [-2, inf], (optional)) – The index of this button, when set a single member of an array can be accessed, when set to -1
>   all array members are used

```
import bpy

class LayoutPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Panel with funny layout"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "TOOL_PROPS"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        cube = bpy.context.scene.objects.get("Cube")
        if cube:
            layout.prop(cube, "location", index=0)
            layout.prop(cube, "rotation_euler", index=0)

bpy.utils.register_class(LayoutPanel)
```